# Retry during timeout when calling webservice in fuse

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, activemq-classic, fuseesb, jbossfuse

i have a requirement to retry for 8 times with an interval of 1 hr while calling webservice is down.Can any one tell me how to implement in Fuse ESB.

The payload is huge so i think the redelivery policy is not a good idea to use.Because it stores the message in memory.

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to ping the webservice you want to call? If you can ping the webservice you could use ping the webservice before you try to call it with your main payload and if the webservice is up then send your message. If not, write the payload to memory and run redelivery policy on the ping for 1 hour.

Comment: Hi David, even I thought of using on exception clause with re delivery policy but my request payload is huge xml with 250 data items will there be any issue if we store the message in memory for such a long interval and if the volume is huge?if so can you suggest what is the best alternative